# Chart.js. How to combine Line chart with stacked Bar chart?

Tags: javascript, angular, charts, chart.js

I am trying to create combined line + stacked bar [chart](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-pxgzss?file=src%2Fmain.ts), but I can't figure out how do this. There are two charts in the example. Chart1 is stacked bar chart, Chart2 is Line chart, basically I need Chart2 with stacked bar chart from Chart1 as background for it, labels for axis must be as in Chart2, Fall, Winter, Spring labels not needed, but without them bar chart does not work. Everything is mashed up when i trying to combine them, options from line chart broke bar chart or vice versa. Is this possible to achieve ?

**Update:**
I combined charts by using [different axisId](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/#axis-id) for each chart, this gives me opportunity to set options to each chart independently of each other.